# Windows could not start the WLAN-AutoConfig service; error 0x080004005

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I'm trying to use a WLAN-Stick (TP Link TL-WN821N) to connect to a wireless network. However, my PC (Windows 10 Pro) doesn't show any wireless networks. When trying to troubleshoot the problem, windows tells me that WLAN AutoConfig is not running. I switched the WLAN autoconfig from manual to automatic, but it doesn't start when I restart windows.
When I try to run it, I get:

> Windows could not start the WLAN-AutoConfig service on Local Computer.
> Error 0x080004005: Unspecified error

Sometimes, and I can't really tell when, I instead get the error:

> Windows could not start the WLAN-AutoConfig service on Local Computer.
> Error 1206:  The network connection profile is corrupted

I already tried everything that I found on google regarding issues with WLAN autoconfig, including:

- Checking that I have the correct drivers for the WLAN stick; uninstalling device and installing with correct hardware version from the product's website
- Verifying that the stick is working (it works fine on a different PC)
- resetting all network profiles using "netsh winsock reset"
- Checking in BIOS if there is an option do enable/disable wifi (I did not find any; msi B550-A PRO)
- Running "Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth" on admin powershell to "fix some corruptions" (according to google)
- Completely reinstalling windows

None of these steps yielded any results. The next step for me would be to completely format my main drive and do a complete clean install, however that would be a very time-consuming measure and I would like to check here if someone has a less severe idea on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by updating my BIOS, after that I was able to manually start WLAN autoconfig. Apparently this is because of an issue regarding some motherboard units (msi B550-A PRO) produced in a certain period of time.

Unfortunately I know all of this due to a hail-mary measure that a friend of mine came up with, so I don't have any sources on the motherboard flaws.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).